# Go To record using TempVars

Tags: vba, ms-access

Just wondering if anyone could help me here? I am having an issue that when adding a new record, it then takes (tempvars) the ID from which the record is inserted. What I need it then to do is to go to that record on another form. However, the current code I have results in the following error message;

"2105: You can't go to the specified record."

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from TblConsumables")

    If IsNull(Me.ConCompany) Or IsNull(Me.txtConName) Then
        MsgBox "Please complete all information before continuing.", vbExclamation
            End
    End If

With rst
    .AddNew
        TempVars!VarConAddID = !ID.Value
        !Company = Me.ConCompany.Value
        !PartName = Me.txtConName.Value
    .Update
End With

    If IsOpen("frmConsumablesDetails") Then
            Forms!frmConsumablesDetails.Refresh
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmConsumablesDetails", acGoTo, Application.TempVars("VarConAddID")
        Call Closefrm("ConFrmAddNewConsumable")
    End If

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: where do you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

You're misinterpreting what `DoCmd.GoToRecord` does.

Let's say `TempVars("VarConAddID")` is 50. Then `DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmConsumablesDetails", acGoTo, Application.TempVars("VarConAddID")` tries to select the 50th record on the subform, not the record where the ID is 50.

If you want to navigate to a record with a specific ID, you can use something like this:

```
Forms!frmConsumablesDetails.RecordSet.FindFirst "ID = " & Application.TempVars("VarConAddID")
```

Comment: I see the logic behind your code. However, it returns an error "3001: Invalid Argument". When I debug the TempVars is working as should.

Comment: Oh, right, `FindFirst` instead of `MoveFirst`. `MoveFirst` is just the first record.

Comment: That has stopped the error message but the record is not changing from the value that is currently on the form.

Comment: I have managed an untidy work around but it is not at all efficient.

`If IsOpen("frmConsumablesDetails") Then
        Call Closefrm("ConFrmAddNewConsumable")
        Call Closefrm("frmConsumablesDetails")
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmConsumablesDetails", , , "ID = " & Application.TempVars("VarConAddID")
    End If`.